# Connect Unauthenticated Federated Identity ID with User Pool

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I'm trying to implement an option in Mobile app (Xamarin) for users to be able to login into App as a guest user.

Right now I'm able to obtain the Federated Identity ID for a guest user. It has a form of AccessKey/SecretKey/Token.

I'm struggling with translating that credentials to accesToken and refreshToken that I get from users, who are generated via user pool.

What could be your suggestions?

Comment: You need to post the token to the [AWS token endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338624/how-to-access-users-email-address-in-cognito-federated-identities/47796072#47796072)

Comment: @Stu thank you for you comment, but I have doubts that I could use any of the credentials that I receive (AccesKey/SecretKey/Token) to obtain a new tokens, because there is no endpoints that took them. The only one that closely match is the refresh token endpoint, but I did not have it :(